# Fitnesse getting inner table value

Tags: fitnesse

Here is an interesting one for you.

So I have a table like this that checks stuff in JSON response.

```
!define innerTable (
|name|whatever|
|email|whatever2|
|hpeon|whatever3|
)

|Check if correct values are returned|
|property name|value is?|
|catalogId|1002|
|productName|Name of the product|
|productStatus|ACTIVE|
|productType|Whatever|
|contactInformation|${prizeTiers}|
```

So how the heck do I get stuff out of contactInformation? :)

Since the values are changing and stuff... And contactInformation is a value in a JSON and not some method name... Any ideas?

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using fitSharp or FitLibrary, embedded tables are used to match collections.  e.g. http://fitsharp.github.com/Fit/CompareList.html

Oops, didn't notice you said contactInformation was in JSON. So you'd have to write a method to return a collection of objects.  That will be different for fitSharp or FitLibrary.

update: fixed link

Comment: Also your link points to an invalid folder or something.. because I'm getting 404. :)